# NoMethodError: undefined method `type' for #<Class>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oracle12c

I have a column called **type_name** in a table for an Oracle 12c DB, whenever I try to add record using Rails console I got below message. **Shall I change the column name from *type_name* to any other name to fix this issue ?**

**Model:**

```
class LicenseTypes < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates :name, :type, presence: true

  def as_json(options = {})
    {
      id: id,
      name: name,
      description: description,
      type_name: type_name
    }
  end
end
```

**Migration:**

```
class CreateLicenseTypes < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :license_types do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :type_name
      t.string :description
      t.integer :created_at
      t.integer :updated_at
    end
  end
end
```

**Code:**

```
LicenseType.create({name: "Car Lic" , type_name: "Car"})
```

**Error:**

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `type' for #<LicenseType:0x76b49d0>
        from org/jruby/RubyBasicObject.java:1633:in `method_missing'
        from C:/jruby-9.1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activemodel-4.2.7/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:433:in `method_missing'
        from C:/jruby-9.1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activemodel-4.2.7/lib/active_model/validator.rb:149:in `block in validate'
        from org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1734:in `each'
        from C:/jruby-9.1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activemodel-4.2.7/lib/active_model/validator.rb:148:in `validate'
        from C:/jruby-9.1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-4.2.7/lib/active_record/validations/presence.rb:5:in `validate'
        from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1808:in `public_send'
        from C:/jruby-9.1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activesupport-4.2.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:455:in `block in make_lambda'
        from C:/jruby-9.1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activesupport-4.2.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:192:in `block in simple'
        from C:/jruby-9.1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activesupport-4.2.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:504:in `block in call'
        from org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1734:in `each'
        from C:/jruby-9.1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activesupport-4.2.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:504:in `call'
        from C:/jruby-9.1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activesupport-4.2.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `__run_callbacks__'
        from C:/jruby-9.1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activesupport-4.2.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_validate_callbacks'
        from C:/jruby-9.1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activemodel-4.2.7/lib/active_model/validations.rb:399:in `run_validations!'
        from C:/jruby-9.1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activemodel-4.2.7/lib/active_model/validations/callbacks.rb:113:in `block in run_validations!'
... 15 levels...
        from C:/jruby-9.1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-4.2.7/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:286:in `block in save'
        from C:/jruby-9.1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-4.2.7/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:301:in `rollback_active_record_state!'
        from C:/jruby-9.1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-4.2.7/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:285:in `save'
        from C:/jruby-9.1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-4.2.7/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:34:in `create'
        from (irb):12:in `<eval>'
        from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:995:in `eval'
        from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1296:in `loop'
        from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1115:in `catch'
        from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1115:in `catch'
        from C:/jruby-9.1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/railties-4.2.7/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
        from C:/jruby-9.1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/railties-4.2.7/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
        from C:/jruby-9.1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/railties-4.2.7/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
        from C:/jruby-9.1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/railties-4.2.7/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
        from C:/jruby-9.1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/railties-4.2.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<main>'
        from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:956:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Can you post your `LicenseType` model code?

Comment: Generally speaking, naming a column `type` is dangerous in Rails... it's one of the unwritten often-used names for STI (and other similar things). Better to rename it. Also: `name` vs `type_name` aren't strongly descriptive names that help a new developer instantly spot what the columns are used for... renaming is good for that purpose too :)

Comment: @GokulM I've added the model.

Comment: @Shiko You have added the migration file and not the model code.

Comment: @GokulM Thanks a lot, now I discovered my problem. I forgot the column "type" in validates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `type` to `type_name` as type can be only use for STI.

`validates :name, :type, presence: true`

to

`validates :name, :type_name, presence: true`

Comment: Discovered my issue when you asked for model. Thanks a lot